# Why does the following use of useSelector break referential equality?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, reference

I was [having an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045742/component-rerendering-when-non-related-parts-of-redux-store-update-in-react-redu) where selecting certain values out of my store would trigger a rerender with any store value update, even if I was selecting values that weren't updating.  It turns out, the issue was that I was doing this:

```js
const transformedValues = useSelector(state => state.some.array).map(value => value);
```

As the answer to the above referenced question points out, this breaks referential equality of `transformedValues`, causing the component to update.

But when I do this, there is no issue, and no unecessary rerender:

```js
const valuesFromStore = useSelector(state => state.some.array);
const transformedValues = valuesFromStore.map(value => value);
```

Why?  What is the difference in these two tactics that in the first one, referential equality of the selector is broken (causing rerender), and in the second, it does not cause a rerender?  What is going on "under the hood" of redux and javascript to make a difference here?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  That *isn't* a problem, and *doesn't* cause a new reference.  `useSelector(state => state.some.value)` *only* causes a re-render when `state.some.value` itself changes.

I know you said in the other question that changing this fixed your issue, but based on what I can see there really shouldn't be any issue with that code in the first place.